# Heroku deploys failing: Error: Unknown error installing "12.x" of node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

Our deploys started failing to heroku yesterday and I can't figure out why, nothing in our codebase changed related to the build/dependencies. I've been trying to debug it and use different combinations of buildpacks for a day now and cant seem to figure it out. Heroku support hasn't been able to help me either.

Essentially it errors out when it goes to install node. Ive tried every version of node and various buildpacks. Prior to the builds failing we werent specifying our versions in the package.json, but I tried doing this with all the different combinations and still no luck. The deploy breaks at this point:

```
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Error: Unknown error installing "12.x" of node
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Let me know any information I could provide or debugging ideas anyone might have, thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe its unrelated to installing node and its just throwing that error, have you tried comparing your code changes against the last stable release?

Comment: yea, the code change from when it deployed successfully and when it stopped was very small ruby tweaks and don't make sense for whats happening..

Comment: even when I tried to redeploy the same code that successfully deployed it breaks now, cant see how this happens other than something on heroku side I cant see

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the QuotaGuard Static IP's Add-On which was prompting us to upgrade, we upgraded and then our deploys started breaking likely because of a cached environment variable on the heroku side for HTTPS_PROXY. I removed this variable and the build worked.

Comment: How did you do this? I get that error and don't know how to solve.. I tried: 
with engines specification in package.json or none I get the same error: with specification: `Error: Unknown error installing "^16.13.1" of node`  without: `Error: Unknown error installing "18.x" of node`